# What is the equivalent of BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_ASSOC in Boost.Hana?

Tags: boost, c++14, boost-fusion, boost-hana, adaptor

In the good old days we used to adapt a `struct` into a Boost.Fusion container or an associative container with

```
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/struct/adapt_struct.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/struct/adapt_assoc_struct.hpp>

struct Person{
    std::string name;
    int age;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
    Person,
    (std::string, name)
    (int, age)
);

struct tag_name;
struct tag_age;

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_ASSOC_STRUCT(
    Person,
    (std::string, name, tag_name)
    (int, age, tag_age));

int main(){}
```

Now with Boost.Hana we can also adapt

```
#include <boost/hana/adapt_struct.hpp>
BOOST_HANA_ADAPT_STRUCT(Person, 
    name,
    age
);
```

**The question: Is there a sort of `BOOST_HANA_ADAPT_ASSOC_STRUCT` (equivalent to `BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_ASSOC_STRUCT`) in Boost.Hana? Or is this done differently now?**

Bonus question: Is there a `BOOST_HANA_ADAPT_TPL`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation of Boost.Fusion the `BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_ASSOC_STRUCT` macro generates boiler plate for modeling 
 Random Access Sequence and Associative Sequence.

With Boost.Hana these additional macros are not needed as you get additional functionality for free without any boiler plate.

For "Associative Sequence", Boost.Hana has the [`Searchable`](http://boostorg.github.io/hana/group__group-Struct.html) concept that provides the [`at_key`](http://boostorg.github.io/hana/group__group-Searchable.html#ga3c1826aee6c6eb577810bb99c5c3e53d) function.

While Boost.Hana does not have iterators for "Random Access Sequence", it does have the functions [`at`](http://boostorg.github.io/hana/group__group-Iterable.html#ga8a484304380eae38f3d9663d98860129) and [`at_c`](http://boostorg.github.io/hana/group__group-Iterable.html#ga4cb99cfbef936cb267e76f66f40f529c) in Boost.Hana's [`Iterable`](http://boostorg.github.io/hana/group__group-Iterable.html) concept.
Unfortunately Boost.Hana's [`Struct`](http://boostorg.github.io/hana/group__group-Struct.html) does not implement these although I believe it could. Perhaps that could be added.

As for `BOOST_HANA_ADAPT_TPL`, Boost.Hana has no macro for facilitating template structs, but users can still implement [`hana::accessors`](http://boostorg.github.io/hana/group__group-Struct.html#ga983a55dbd93d766fd37689ea32e4ddfb) to make a [`Struct`](http://boostorg.github.io/hana/group__group-Struct.html) without any macro.

You can search `boost::hana::Struct`s members by their name with a compile-time string:

```
#define BOOST_HANA_CONFIG_ENABLE_STRING_UDL
#include <boost/hana.hpp>
#include <string>

namespace hana = boost::hana;
using namespace hana::literals;

struct Person {
  std::string name;
  int age;
};

BOOST_HANA_ADAPT_STRUCT(
  Person,
  name,
  age
);

int main()
{
  Person person{"Joe", 42};

  // hana::Searchable search by key
  hana::at_key(person, "name"_s);
  hana::at_key(person, "age"_s);
}
```